# Performance of panning/zooming LineSeries on a high frequency signal

Tags: performance, oxyplot

### Description

I noticed a significant difference in the performance of OxyPlot when a LineSignal of a high frequency sine is plotted vs. a LineSignal of a low frequency sine. (It doesn't matter if it is a sine or any other signal. I just used a sine.)

When I use low frequency (where you clearly see the wave of the sine) rendering, panning and zooming are very fast. However when I use high frequency (where you can not identify a curve, the whole plot area is covered by the signal) rendering, panning and zooming are significantly slow.

Apparently the amount of points is not the root of the problem, since I use 100_000 points for each scenario. It looks like the area which is covered by color is crucial. The more of the area is covered the longer the reaction is.

Using the ScreenPoint Decimator helps a bit but the difference is still huge.

I was not able to test the behavior with OxyPlot.SkiaSharp, since mouse operations seems to not work there.

### How to reproduce

- Checkout the github project on https://github.com/chriglburri/OxyPlotRenderingPerformanceDemo
- Read the README.MD how to proceed
- As written in the README, comment the lines where a signal with high or low frequency is rendered to
- compare the performance of the application

Does anyone have an idea how I can improve the rendering performance?

(This question is basically a duplicate of a github issue for which I got no response: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1895)

Answer (score 0):

Using the XamlRenderContext improves the performance significantly. You can create your own PlotView class like this

```cs
public class XamlPlotView : PlotView
{
  protected override IRenderContext CreateRenderContext()
  {
    return new XamlRenderContext(this.Canvas);
  }
}
```

Then you use it in the xaml file of your view like this:

```cs
<local:XamlPlotView x:Name="Plot">
</local:XamlPlotView>
```